# Redmine, where does it store tracker specific issue status in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, redmine

I'm trying to query Redmine MySQL database. 
I have tracker table and issue status table. Each tracker has different drop down issue status.

For example, tracker ABC may have a drop down menu of issue statuses of NEW, IN PROGRESS, and CLOSED while tracker DEF may have issue statuses of USED, and CLOSED. (but issue status table will have all of the statuses listed.)
My question is where does redmine store the relationship between tracker and issue status? I've been looking into all the tables but cannot figure it out.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If I'm right, Trackers and IssueStatus are related to workflows so the code `https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/workflow_rule.rb` should give you a clue about where to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 tables which are relevant in regards to issue statuses.

It's **issues**, **issue_statuses**, **journals** and **journal_details**.
[image]

In issues you have status_id column, which holds integer values, representing issue status id's (1 = new, etc.. ) based upon your values in issue_statuses table.

And in journals and journal_details is a trace of history of changes on one issue, so journal keeps issue id, while journal_details has a old_value and new_value fields indicating the change which occured on that particular issue, connected via id's.

But in RubyOnRails on which Redmine is based upon, much like in CakePHP and similar frameworks, relations are done through model, so you should rather use some ERM tool to look for relations like **rails-erd** or **RailRoady** tool, instead of trying to figure out relations from database model, and you are advised not to write sql code, but rather to use activerecord for querying the database, because SQL codes differ and Redmine works on different platforms like MySql, MSSql, Posgresql...